# Redis: who is eating my field when piping llen results through awk?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, redis, pipe

Redis: 2.0.4, 2.4.1, ...

I'm going to write a Nagios plugin to check the length of a list. Here's my script:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

help()
{
    echo "Usage: $0 <host> <port> <key> -w <warning> -c <critical>"
}

case "$1" in
    --help)
        help 
        exit
        ;;
esac

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    help
    exit 3
fi
if [ $# -ne "7" ]; then
    help
    exit 4
fi
if [ $4 !="-w" -o $6 !="-c" ]; then
    help
    exit 5
fi

REDIS_CLI="/usr/local/redis/bin/redis-cli"
LLEN=`$REDIS_CLI -h $1 -p $2 llen $3 | awk '{ print $2 }'`
if [ $LLEN -lt $5 ]; then
    echo "$3.llen:$2 OK - $LLEN | $3.llen:$2=$LLEN;$5;$7"
    exit 0
elif [ $LLEN -ge $5 -a $LLEN -lt $7 ]; then
    echo "$3.llen:$2 WARNING - $LLEN | $3.llen:$2=$LLEN;$5;$7"
    exit 1
elif [ $LLEN -ge "$7" ]; then   
    echo "$3.llen:$2 CRITICAL - $LLEN | $3.llen:$2=$LLEN;$5;$7"
    exit 2
fi
```

but I got the following error when running `/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/redis_llen.sh 192.168.5.201 2468 -w 90000 -c 100000`:

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/redis_llen.sh: line 31: [: -lt: unary operator expected
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/redis_llen.sh: line 34: [: too many arguments
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/redis_llen.sh: line 37: [: -ge: unary operator expected
```

Running it in debug mode, I found that the `LLEN`'s value is... blank. Since the `llen queue_1` returns the right result:

```
# /usr/local/redis/bin/redis-cli -h 192.168.5.201 -p 2468 llen queue_1
(integer) 965
```

why does the pipeline swallow my fields? (not only to `awk` but also `echo`, `tee`, ...):

```
# /usr/local/redis/bin/redis-cli -h 192.168.5.201 -p 2468 llen queue_1 | \
awk '{ print $0 }'
961
```

I can check the number of fields and print the corresponding as a workaround:

```
| awk '{ if (NF == 2) print $2; else print $1 }'`
```

but I really want to know why does it happen? Is there any null or special character between `(interger)` and the number?

PS: it seems that some other Redis version (for e.x: 1.3.7) doesn't get this issue.

Comment: you seem like you know about shell debugging, did you `set -vx`, yes? If not, add that near top of script to see execution trace AND values of variables after they are evaluated. ALSO, you can use `| cat -vet` appended as needed to see some of the ctrl-chars that are included in your pipeline (only as a tmp aid to debugging individual chuncks of code, as you show near the bottom of your question). A possible suspect, `^M` the DOS '\r` CR char. Good luck.

Comment: As I said above, I see the value of LLEN is blank when running in debug mode. `| cat -vet` also returns only the number. I'm sure there's no `^M` in my file (because it was wrote on the Linux machine). You can test only the `redis-cli` command on your own machine to see what's happen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're experiencing is `redis-cli` selecting different outputs depending on what `STDOUT` is. If `STDOUT` is a TTY, `redis-cli` will output using it's "standard" formatting. Otherwise, the "raw" formatting is the default:

```
--raw            Use raw formatting for replies (default when STDOUT is not a tty)
```

As you see from the help, or the above, you can specify `--raw` to always have it output the "raw" format (without type qualifiers, etc). What I found out digging through the source for this, is that there is also a CSV mode, using `redis-cli --csv`.

**Edit:** To force the "standard" output, even when `STDOUT` is not a TTY, you can set the environment variable `FAKETTY`:

```
FAKETTY=1 redis-cli llen some_list | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Or

```
redis-cli --raw llen some_list | awk '{ print $1 }'
```